# Using binary image in html tag - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, base64

I am having some trouble with displaying a binary image in my HTML from a database. First I am getting the image from the db, and then encoding the response as base 64 using the following function:

`$scope.frontImage=$window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(response)));`

Then in my html I am passing that into the img tag's source like so:

`src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{frontImage}}"`

This, however, is not working. When I inspect the element it only says . The string I am getting from the btoa function looks like this (except obviously much longer):

`77+977+977+977+9ABBKRklGAAECAQEsASwAAO+/ve+/vRLvv71FeGlmAABNTQAqAAAACAAHARIAAwAAAAEAAQAAARoABQAAAAEAAABiARsABQAAAAEAAABqASgAAwAAAAEAAgAAATEAAgAAAB0AAAByATIAAgAAABQAAADvv73vv71pAAQAAAABAAAA77+9`

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Comment: I looked at that and a few other threads that seemed similar but couldn't find an answer that worked for me.

Comment: we don't have a lot to go on.  Break the problem into pieces.  Start with a good base64 converted image, use that data to display the image.  Once you know that is working then focus on making sure the data is getting from point a to point b.  Keep splitting it into smaller halves.  Sorry if this seems vague.